# Disable IPv6 entirely on a Xiaomi Mi A3

Tags: 9.0-pie, xiaomi, android-one, ipv6

I am running Android One 9 on a Xiaomi Mi A3 and am trying to stop it from using IPv6 DNS servers, as they are essentially turning my RPI4 running Pi-Hole into a useless lump of silicon. How can I do this without having the phone ignore my instructions??

I have tried setting the WiFi connection to use a static IP and DNS info, as well as both the `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.wlan0.disable_ipv6=1` and the older `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6` commands but to no avail...the file retains the value `0` and my phone insists on using one IPv4 and one IPv6 DNS server no matter what I try!

Please help me end this madness! MTIA :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I finally managed to configure this at a network-wide level by disabling IPv6 on my router. Now Pi-Hole works across **all** my devices. Happy days! :D